# MVC 5 Application Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I want to store some settings in the application, ones that I can only read from (which i think is pretty much the idea).

How do I inject the reader, I'm not entirely sure how to read application settings in the first place or whether it already has an interface to inject.

I would either want something like this:

```
public interface IPropertyService
{
    string ReadProperty(string key);
}
```

and then implement:

```
public class DefaultPropertyService : IPropertyService
{
    public string ReadProperty(string key)
    {
        // what ever code that needs to go here
        // to call the application settings reader etc.

        return ApplicationSetting[key];
    }
}
```

Any help on this subject would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to store configuration setting inside my asp.net mvc application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044712/best-way-to-store-configuration-setting-inside-my-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Its not quite a duplicate, mine is asking for an injectable service orientated solution, not just to storing the config, I knew sorta how it would be stored, just wanted to know the rest

Comment: What does `ones that I can only read from` that mean?  The word I in this context is ambiguous.  Do you mean you the human?  Do you mean your program?  Do you mean only the code you wrote can read it?

Comment: I mean `readonly` as in a `readonly` property, but thanks the question has been answered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, and you're basically there.  For the web, configuration settings are stored in the `Web.Config`, under the `AppSettings` node.  You can access those in code by using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.  Here is a sample implementation of an injectable service that accesses the config.

```
public interface IPropertyService {

    string ReadProperty(string key);

    bool HasProperty(string key);

} // end interface IPropertyService

public class WebConfigurationPropertyService : IPropertyService {

    public WebConfigurationPropertyService() {

    } // end constructor

    public virtual bool HasProperty(string key) {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Select((string x) => x).Contains(key);
    } // end method HasProperty

    public virtual string ReadProperty(string key) {
        string returnValue = String.Empty;
        if(this.HasProperty(key)) {
            returnValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        } // end if
        return returnValue;
    } // end method ReadProperty

} // end class WebconfigurationPropertyService
```

Comment: why are they virtual methods?

Comment: Generally speaking if something is exposed by an interface, it should be able to be overridden, unless there is a specific reason not to (Open / Closed Principle).  This is more a personal preference than a requirement.  You could for example if you were creating a "base" website, inherit this service in the derived website and override the methods to uppercase the config names.

Comment: So virtual just allows these properties to be overridden at some point then

Comment: That is correct.  For more info on this, see: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/OCP.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Where are you trying to store your application settings? Does the appSettings section of the Web.Config not suffice?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="someSetting" value="SomeValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

and then read your setting this way

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someSetting"]
```